# Ember PAge restriction

Tags: javascript, ember.js

how to restrict user from accessing page like profile,change password in URL before login session begin for user

example : localhost/profile is access able even though user is not looggd in. how do i restrict it

Answer (score 0):

Official guide has a good explanation about your case. You can check out the following [page](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/); you can make use of `willTransition`, `beforeModel` and similar hooks provided from `route` as described.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to note that all security must be implemented on server side first, because client side (ember app in this case) is very vulnerable.

As for your question, I recommend to use [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) addon. It does exactly what you need.